# How can I assign without using self.attribute = in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

SO,

I have been working on this for a while, I posted a much larger question that didn't get any replies, but I'll ask a much simpler one here.

My question is, how else can I assign something without using self.attribute = in the following context:

```
 def photo_from_url(url)
   remote_photo = open(url)
   def remote_photo.original_filename;base_uri.path.split('/').last; end
   **self.photo = remote_photo**
   self.save
 end
```

I need to make photo_from_url a class method so I can call it from delayed_job however when I add self, it gives me "no method found photo=".

Please help! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: you want to create new object each time you call this method:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.photo_from_url(url)
    ...

    new(:photo => remote_photo).save!
  end
end
```

Option 2: you want to update existing object, then you need to get object id you want to modify:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.photo_from_url(url)
    ...

    id = # here you find id, e.g. from url 
    find(id).update_attributes!(:photo => remote_photo)
  end
end
```

Comment: Victor, you are an absolute life saver. This worked. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 2):

A class method, by definition, does not reference any specific object instance. Therefore, you must have a way to get the object you want to modify. The simplest solution would be to pass a reference of that object into your class method and use that instead of `self`.

```
class Foo
  def self.photo_from_url(url, obj)
     ... 
     obj.photo = remote_photo
     ...
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
foo = Foo.new # creates a new instance of Foo
Foo.photo_from_url("http://example.com/photo/12341", foo)
```

Notice how I am calling `photo_from_url` as a class method? That is because it is operating on the `Foo` class and not an instance of `Foo`, which happens to be `foo` here.

---

Here is some literature on the difference between class and instance methods:

[Class and Instance Methods in Ruby](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

Comment: Hey Jeremy - thanks for getting back to me. What you suggest looks like it could work, but I have a question (amateur coder here). What are you passing through to obj? An ID maybe?

Comment: An instance of the object that contains the `photo` property that you want to set. I'll add an example usage scenario to my answer.

Comment: What a point passing obj? If you know it you should probably use instance method.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, appreciate your help. Ran with Victors answer as it made most immediate sense, and fitted in best with my existing code. A very huge thanks for your input. I will be reading that material!

Comment: @Victor: I was looking at it from a generic point of view, and not really from an ActiveRecord point of view. My fault.